# How to study maths.

Tags: soft-question

I opted to study mathematics at college level. To study maths one must cultivate following habits:
1. Practice, Practice & More Practice
2. Review Errors
3. Master the Key Concepts
4. Understand your Doubts
5. Create a Distraction Free Study
Environment
6. Create a Mathematical Dictionary.
7. Apply Maths to Real World Problems.

This site is a hub of learned men and genius people.So I want  you gentlemen to suggest me how to study mathematics.

Comment: "So I want you gentlemen [...]" What about the ladies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For one thing, not all  gentlemen. Some of us are ladies. Always consider *all* possible cases (a common error in math).

The first vital thing is your attitude. You must cultivate an attitude that you can and will succeed. Some days you may meet difficulties and setbacks, but these are just opportunities to go back and learn more. Each time you overcome a difficulty you have gained skills. Progress will be fast some days and slow others. Be calm and continue working. If you can't progress in one subject or problem, work on others until you can either find new resources or think up a new idea.

Second, it is vital to cultivate the "big picture". Many students and even teachers bog down in memorization of more and more formulas and details and trivia. This is not mathematics. Mathematics is a method of logical reasoning and of problem-solving and a structure of abstract ideas based on logic. Of course you need to learn formulas and methods, but they should never be your sole focus.

Third, seek out good textbooks and good teachers. Both good texts and good teachers challenge you a lot by presenting new ideas and new ways of doing things, but they don't go too far and leave you massively frustrated. They are supportive but don't do everything for you. Also, good texts and good teachers have good focus and steady progress towards goals; they do not just build up masses of trivia.

Good luck. With modern resources to find material on the internet and sites like this one you can go a long way.